# $1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + \ldots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \leq 2\sqrt{n}$ by mathematical induction

Tags: induction

I need the following by the principle of Mathematical induction:

\begin{align*}
1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + \ldots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \leq 2\sqrt{n}
\end{align*}
I can easily find out the base case for n=1 is true.

However, I can't find the proof in the induction step.

I assume:
\begin{align*}
1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \leq 2\sqrt{n}
\end{align*}

To proof:
\begin{align*}
1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + \ldots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} \leq 2\sqrt{n+1}
\end{align*}
Can someone help me find a way to proof the inductive step too?

Thank you!

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/509840/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/653530/42969

Answer (score 1):

Based on the induction assumption one has
\begin{align*}
1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + \ldots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} \leq 2\sqrt{n} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} \leq 2\sqrt{n+1}
\end{align*}

The last step takes place because
\begin{align*}
2\sqrt{n+1} - 2\sqrt{n} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} & = 2(\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}) - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\\\\
& = \frac{2\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})\sqrt{n+1}} = \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})\sqrt{n+1}} > 0
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Like any induction proof, use the induction hypothesis. You have an assumption. That assumption lets you simplify away almost all of the left-hand side, at the cost of making it a little bit bigger. Hopefully it is still smaller than $2\sqrt{n+1}$, though.

Answer (score 0):

The increment from the $n$ sum to the $n+1$ sum is

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}=\frac{2}{\color{blue}{\sqrt{n+1}}+\sqrt{n+1}}<\frac{2}{\color{blue}{\sqrt{n}}+\sqrt{n+1}}$

and then

$\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}}=2(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})$

from the difference of squares factorization.  Can you see how to do the induction now?